# Fitting a polynomial with a known intercept

Tags: r, linear-regression, polynomials, intercept

I am using `lm(y~poly(x,2))` to fit a second-order polynomial to my data. But I just couldn't find a way to specify a known intercept value. How can I fit a polynomial model with a known intercept value (say 'k') using `lm`?

Comment: Maybe remove the intercept parameter with `- 1` in the formula, and the subtract the known intercept from your data?

Comment: Thank you @BrodieG. But as Ben pointed out `offset(k)` would be more explicit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
 lm(y~-1+x+I(x^2)+offset(k))
```

should do it.

- `-1` suppresses the otherwise automatically added intercept term
- `x` adds a linear term
- `I(x^2)` adds a quadratic term; the `I()` is required so that R interprets `^2` as squaring, rather than taking an interaction between `x` and itself (which by formula rules would be equivalent to `x` alone)
- `offset(k)` adds the known constant intercept

I don't know whether `poly(x,2)-1` would work to eliminate the intercept; you can try it and see.  Subtracting the offset from your data should work fine, but `offset(k)` might be slightly more explicit.  You might have to make `k` a vector (i.e. replicate it to the length of the data set, or better include it as a column in the data set and pass the data with `data=...`

Comment: `offset` looks like a great function to do this with; the help for it is a little confusing: "An offset is a term to be added to a linear predictor, such as in a generalised linear model, with known coefficient 1 rather than an estimated coefficient."  Known coefficient 1?  This must be a typo.

Comment: no, it's just confusing.  The point is that the equation is then `y=b0+b1*x1+b2*x2+1*offset` rather than `y=b0+b1*x1+b2*x2+b3*offset` (where `b3` would be the "estimated coefficient").

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker. It works. But to tell the truth, I don't fully understand  this formula and I can't find help from R.  Could you explain each element of this formula or direct me to where I can find the explanation?

Comment: Ohh... I haven't noticed that you edited the answer till now. thank you very much.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me .... except I did have to generate a k vector as you suggest